# docker-compose only works if yml file in home directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For some reason, on Ubuntu 20.04 `docker-compose up` only works if my docker compose yaml file is in the user's home directory.

I've uninstalled docker, installed it with snap, installed with apt and no difference.

Why is this? I've never seen this on any other server and for some reason this happens here.

How do I fix this so I can run docker-compose from a directory containing a docker-compose.yml file and have it read the pwd?

I have tried the -f option and it does not help.

Comment: Do you have any `COMPOSE_` variables set in the environment? Any aliases/functions in your shell profile?

Comment: docker-compose by default looks for file in current directory. if you want to pick a specific file in different directory, use this : docker-compose -f /location/to/file.yaml up -d.

Comment: @YashSoni - I understand, and the issue is that it's not working like you say. No matter where I am in the filesystem and which -f path I give, it only works if docker-compose.yml is in my home directory...

Comment: can you share the error and directory structure

Comment: It appears to have something to do with what volume group the current directory is on. Something with the way the LVM is setup is causing this...